# sbt - java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, exceptions

I installed `sbt` following this instructions [Getting Started - setup](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#id1), on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I run `sbt` I see next output:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ sbt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/nazar_art/.sbt/boot/update.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.<init>(Checks.java:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:275)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jnaLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:120)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.jnaLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:115)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:94)
    at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:290)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/nazar_art/.sbt/boot/update.log (No such file or directory)
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ sudo sbt
[sudo] password for nazar_art: 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

For be complietly sure I repeat executable script:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ chmod u+x ~/bin/sbt
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ which sbt
/home/nazar_art/bin/sbt
```

***UPDATE:***

`update.log` didn't exist. I created at `~/bin/.sbt/boot/update.log`.

And now when I tried run `sbt` I see output:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/bin/.sbt/boot$ sbt
No command 'sbt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'skt' from package 'latex-sanskrit' (main)
 Command 'sb2' from package 'scratchbox2' (universe)
 Command 'sbd' from package 'cluster-glue' (main)
 Command 'mbt' from package 'mbt' (universe)
 Command 'sbmt' from package 'atfs' (universe)
 Command 'lbt' from package 'lbt' (universe)
 Command 'st' from package 'suckless-tools' (universe)
 Command 'sb' from package 'lrzsz' (universe)
```

***Update:***

I moved this file `update.log` exactly `home/nazar_art/.sbt/boot`
But after I run `sbt` I catch the same result, but with `Permission denied`:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/.sbt/boot$ pwd
/home/nazar_art/.sbt/boot
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/.sbt/boot$ ls 
update.log
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/.sbt/boot$ sbt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/nazar_art/.sbt/boot/update.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.<init>(Checks.java:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:266)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jnaLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.jnaLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:106)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:85)
    at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:281)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/nazar_art/.sbt/boot/update.log (Permission denied)
```

***- Why this happen?

 - How to solve this issue?***

Comment: Its unable to locate the log file within the specified directory .  You should create an empty text file in that location, provide it the proper permmissions, to see if you can get past the log file error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check to make sure that the `~/.sbt/boot` exists. If it does not, then you might have to create it. If it does, try executing `touch ~/.sbt/boot/update.log` as your user to create the file and set it's permissions as necessary.

Comment: I updated question.

Comment: It can't find the `sbt` command. The last time toy executed it, you were in the base home folder. Try going back up to the home folder and try again?

Comment: I updated question. I can't understand why it trows `Permission denied`. I'm `su`. Any suggestions.

Comment: Is the update.log file set to be writable at all?